# Can't connect to Azure Devops using Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, azure-devops

I'm using eclipse 2019, and I'm trying to integrate it with my company's Azure DevOps, or rather one specific project/repo in that.

After some quick googling, I found a tutorial (which I followed) that involved installing some software through eclipse for Team Explorer Everywhere, a plugin that supposedly performs this automation. However, after installing said plugin and attempting to connect to my company's Devops project, I get stuck in an authentication loop. More specifically, once I point it to the project's url from Azure Devops and give it the correct credentials, Eclipse asks me to click a link and paste a code it gives me into a field in that link once I sign in on the web. I do this, and the website tells me that authentication has been successful and that I should close the browser window. So, I do that. Then I hit "OK" in Eclipse, and the popup I've been in closes.

Now, this is where one might THINK that I would be connected to the Azure repo, but instead when the popup closes it just brings me back to the part where it asks me for a project url, with no changes having been made. I can complete these steps ad infinitum with no difference.

I've tried reinstalling the plugin, using a few different versions of eclipse (like Neon), and several different source urls.

I'd love to share any error messages, but I get nothing. It just blankly returns to the start of the process. The end result I'm looking for is for my Azure repo and and an Eclipse project to be synced.

Comment: Could you please share the tutorial here, so that we could reproduce this issue by following that tutorial?